# In KnockoutJS, is there a specific order in which computed values must be declared?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I get a javascript runtime error when I run the code below.  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` in `dep3` when accessing `self.dep2().name`.

The error goes away if I move the declaration of `dep2` above that of `dep1`.  Is this a bug in Knockout or something I'm doing wrong?  It seems to me that `dep3` is being recomputed as a result of `dep1` changing before `dep2` has been recomputed but I would have expected Knockout to be able to handle this scenario.

```js
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;

    self.root = ko.observable(null);

    self.dep1 = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.root() ? self.root().prop1 : null;
    });

    self.dep2 = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.root() ? self.root().prop2 : null;
    });

    self.dep3 = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.dep1()) {
            return self.dep2().name;
        }
    });
}

globalViewModel = new ViewModel();

globalViewModel.root({
    prop1: {name: "ThisIsPropOne"},
    prop2: {name: "thisIsPropTwo"}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the way that the dependencies are evaluated. The change to `root` will trigger `dep1` and `dep2` to be re-evaluated, but the change to `dep1` triggers `dep3` first.

In this case, one option is to throttle `dep3` like:

```
self.dep3 = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.dep1()) {
        return self.dep2().name;
    }
}).extend({ throttle: 1 });
```

Otherwise, checkout Michael Best's deferred updates plugin here: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates, which will handle this properly in a more robust way than just throttling.